# Interacting and updating your list view with server events

Tags: android

Can any body elaborate with sample code how to use `onNewIntent` inside of a `ListActivity` class so that I can dynamically update my `ListView` while it is displaying?

**Edit :**
As a newbie in android developement i was confused and stressed to ask this. 
The real thing what i was looking to interact and update your listview dynamically with server events. Hopes down votes will be recount again !!!

Comment: There is no change in onNewIntent usage for listactivity and normal activity.. you can use intent passed in onNewIntent to process your data.

Comment: The way you've asked it sounds a bit like a homework assignment, which  is why I decided to post only the conceptual use and not an example.

Comment: I edited my question to regret my mistake as i was newbie to android and was blocked to ask further questions here ... i tried hard to help others and getting back my previledge .. only upvote can save me now..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible use case is a Service which sends results to your Activity.

The Activity's `onNewIntent()` method receives the Intent which was passed to the Activity. From there you can pass that Intent to a method which processes it.

That is, it extracts the data you need and updates the ListView with fresh data.

Comment: i am new to android, can you please give a sample code for that, it will be really very helful to me.